# What is the ideal way to handle two different types of futures where one future is dependent on the other future?

Tags: java, akka, future

I'm looking at AKKA's Java Futures API, and I see a lot of ways to handle multiple futures of the same type, but I don't see anything that pops out at me for handling futures of different types. I'm guessing that I'm making this more complicated than it is.

Anyways let's say we have two different Actors: actorA and actorB. They are based on different classes and they each return a different Future. However, actorB is dependent on a Future from actorA. Is the following logic, how to best handle this case?

```
Future<A> a = actorA.sendRequestReplyFuture(...);

Future<B> b = actorB.sendRequestReplyFuture(a);
```

How about if we have a list of actorAs and actorBs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WARNING, just written from memory, might not compile OOTB:

```
Future<B> b = actor.sendRequestReplyFuture().flatMap( new akka.japi.Function<A,Future<B>>() {
  public Future<B> apply(A a) {
     return actor.sendRequestReplyFuture(a);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just wrap them, as you have, but with one slight change - pass the *result* of a into b.

```
Future a = actorA.sendRequestReplyFuture(...);

Future b = actorB.sendRequestReplyFuture(a.get());
```

This arrangement just means that `actorB.sendRequestReplyFuture()` won't get called until  `actorA.sendRequestReplyFuture()` has finished. Nothing wrong with that, in fact, I *like* the pattern you've got there.

Comment: hmmm question: is this just as efficient from the perspective of non-blocking as using as flatMap call?

Comment: Easily gets unwieldly in Java, but yes, there's a flatMap for our Java API for Future as well.